# sabre api to search flights with passanger info

Tags: sabre

My app requires an "Explore Destionations" functionallity, something simillar to Google Flights' Explore Destionations featrue.

In theory, Destination Finder would have been perfect for the job. The problem is, Destination Finder doesn't seem to provide a way to search for one way trips. In other words, you have to provide a return date.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achive this, Either by using Destination Finder or using a different API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bargain Finder Max, which is another Sabre Search API for flights, provides support One Way options, Round trip and Multi Destination Shopping inquiries, although It is not an Inspirational Shopping Service

Have you checked this out?
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max